# Find all possible solutions of $a^2+b^2+ab=1011$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Find all possible solutions of $$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=2022$$

We can simply take $$x-y=a, y-z=b, z-x=-(a+b)\implies a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2=2022\implies a^2+b^2+ab=1011.$$

We can use modular arithmetic and by taking $\pmod 3$ we get $a,b\equiv 1\pmod 3.$

Morover, $a,b$ are odd. And $a,b\equiv (1,1) \pmod 4$ or $a,b\equiv (3,3)\pmod 4.$

Also, $$(a^2+b^2+ab)(a-b)=(a^3-b^3).$$
I used wolfram alpha and got the 12 solutions, but is there a non-calculative way?

Thanks.

Comment: What does non-calculative mean? Note that $a^2 + b^2 + ab \geq \frac34 a^2$ and hence there are only finitely many values to check. By the way you didn't state anywhere that $x, y, z$ or $a, b$ should be integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better bound if you want to check:

If
$a^2+b^2+ab=n$
then
$2n
=2a^2+2b^2+2ab
=a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2
\ge a^2+1+(a+1)^2
=2a^2+2a+2
$
so
$n 
\ge a^2+a+1
=a^2+a+\frac14+\frac34
=(a+\frac12)^2+\frac34
$
or
$a
\le \sqrt{n-\frac34}-\frac12
$.

Comment: Note that your bound gives $a\le 31$ so you cannot reach the solution $a=34, b=-29$, this is because you supposed $b\in\mathbb N$ (i.e. $b\ge 1$) and de facto eliminated negative solutions, so you reach only the $(29,5)$ solution (which is effectively less than 31).

Comment: True. Negative values require further consideration. Maybe replace b by -b and see what bounds appear.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you set $s=a+b$ and $p=ab$ then $p=s^2-1011$.

And $a,b$ are roots of $x^2-sx+p=0$ of discriminant $\Delta=4044-3s^2$

If there are integer solutions then $\Delta\ge 0$ and a perfect square, so you only get to test $\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{4044}3}\rfloor=36$ values for $s$.

You'll find $(s,a,b)$ triplets :

```
                          5, 34, -29
                          29, 34, -5
                          34, 29, 5
```

To which you need to add the symmetrical values ($a,b$ can be exchanged, and both signs reversed, sign of $s$ too).
It is still brute force but greatly reduced to only $36$ possible outcomes.